# TypeORM get data where id in jsonb array

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have one entity :

```
@Entity()
export class Training {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column('jsonb')
  workoutExercises: Exercise[];
}
```

Exercise entity:

```
@Entity()
export class Exercise {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;
}
```

Example of data :

```
[
  {
    "workoutName": "Monday",
    "workoutExercises": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "sets": 4,
        "weight": 100,
        "repetitions": 10
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "workoutName": "Sunday",
    "workoutExercises": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "sets": 4,
        "weight": 100,
        "repetitions": 10
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

**I would like to find the entity with id exercise id 1.**

After abdul Samad answer, I tried this :

```
this.createQueryBuilder('training')
      .where(`:exerciseId IN ("training"."workoutExercises"->>id)`, {
        exerciseId,
      })
      .getMany();
```

This returns me an empty array. Should have returned something.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.createQueryBuilder('training')
      .where('workoutExercises->>id IN (:exerciseId)', { exerciseId })
      .getMany();
```

hope this would work :).

Comment: This returns me a new error saying "column "workoutexercises" does not exist". Further more should not be something like `.where(':exerciseId IN (workoutExercises->>id)', { exerciseId })` ? exerciseId is an id and workoutExercises is the array of Exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.createQueryBuilder('training')
    .select()
    .where('training.workoutExercises ::jsonb @> :workoutExercises', { workoutExercises: JSON.stringify([{ id: exerciseId }]) })
    .execute();
```

had similar case, try this!